# Issue with ECEF coordinates in Paraview

Tags: python, coordinates, paraview

I have two points in ECEF (Earth-Centered Earth-Fixed) coordinates. In Python, Point B is correctly plotted NE wrt point A (X and Y coords of point B are larger than X and Y coords of point A, so point B is northern and eastern than point A). However, in Paraview Point B is plotted SE wrt point A. Why is that?

Here are the 2 points coordinates:
Point A
4555559.744944858 1060883.0890389425 4306896.852174505
Point B
4577543.101426799 1106878.8513717724 4242391.820340498